# Can I use the dot character (.) for a field name in Mongo DB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm using MongoDb to store JSON data. One of the documents I have contains a deeply nested JSON with values such as the following:

......

```
"value-3.4": {
                  "submit-message": {
                     "enabled": "false"
                  },
                  "dlr-tlvs": {
                     "parse-value": "true",

                  }
               }
            }
```

...

I've got a node.js application using "mongodb": "^3.5.3" which connects to my DB reads, the json data and try to push it to the database using something like the following. Note that datito is the json object that comes from an external file.

```
 try {
                                                     db.collection('config').insertOne(
                                                         datito
                                                     ).then(function(err) {
                                                      console.log(err);
                                                      // expected output: "Success!"
                                                    })
                                                  } catch (e) {
                                                     console.log(e);
                                                  }
```

The problem is that when I try to push the data, I get an error because the field name contains a "." 
I've read that since Mongo 3.6, https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#Restrictions-on-Field-Names this shouldn't be a problem. However, it seems that the latest version published in npm is 3.5.3.

I've also followed these instructions to update Mongo to 3.6 https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.6/installation/ but it seems that it will make no difference as I'm pushing the data from my nodejs application rather than the Mongo shell. Does it make sense?

Could you please advise if I'm getting confused between my mongodb version in my nodejs application vs the Mongo DB version I have 4.2.3?

When I run mongo --version in my CLI I've got:

MongoDB shell version v4.2.3

But my nodejs application seems to be using 3.5.3. Is this assumption correct and hence I should rename the field of my json to not contain "."?

I appreciate your help.

Thanks

Comment: The code snippet you shared from your nodeJS app(pushing to the DB) does not seem complete.

Comment: What your NodeJS application is using is not the same as what you have in your terminal, so their version difference does not really matter on this issue. The `mongo` from your terminal is the MongoDB shell interface that comes along with the installation, your NodeJS app is using a driver that connects to the `mongod`(MongoDB server) process directly.

Comment: Hi @OTZ, yep. It's just illustrative. I needed clarification on what you just mentioned, so it means that since the latest version on npm is 3.5.3 my app can't benefit from the updates/fixes on Mongo DB 3.6 until a new nodejs version is published, right?

Comment: Nope, you don't need a new nodejs version in this context. The mongodb driver(version 3.5) from npm is well compatible with all the recent stable release of MongoDB (3.6 included). For more details on compatibility issues, check [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/driver-compatibility-reference/#reference-compatibility-mongodb-node)

Comment: The difference between the NodeJS driver and the actual MongoDB installation can be pretty tricky, I suggest you ask that as a different question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is stated in the docs that MongoDB(version 3.6 upwards) works well with field names containing dots(.), it is not recommended:

> IMPORTANT
>
> The MongoDB Query Language cannot always meaningfully express queries
>   over documents whose field names contain these characters (see
>   SERVER-30575).
>
> Until support is added in the query language, the use of $ and . in
>   field names is not recommended and is not supported by the official MongoDB drivers.

[Source](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#Restrictions-on-Field-Names)

Notice it also stated that using field names containing dots(.) is not supported by official MongoDB drivers, one of which is what you are using, most likely this is why you are having error on DB insertion.